# Validating a child ASP.NET MVC view-model that is non-mandatory in its parent, but which has mandatory fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am fairly new to ASP.NET MVC and trying work out how to validate a view model of type `AlphaViewModel` that is the argument for a `Create` controller method.

The view model is the following.

```
public class AlphaViewModel
{
    [HiddenInput]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    bool HasBeta { get; set; }

    public BetaViewModel Beta { get; set; } = new BetaViewModel(); // Always initialize otherwise null exception when trying to set its values.
}

public class BetaViewModel
{
    [HiddenInput]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Area { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to set all the properties above through the same UI with the same Save button.

However, the `Beta` property is optional in `AlphaViewModel` so it can be null. If the `Beta` property is not null, then all its properties (`Location`, `Area`) are mandatory.

In the UI, I can have a checkbox which sets `HasBeta` to false and then doesn't show the fields for `BetaViewModel`. However, ASP.NET-MVC's validation is still firing in this case and the `Location` and `Action` fields receive warning messages in the UI stating that they have not been set.

One option would be to turn off validation on the properties of `BetaViewModel` e.g. on `ModelState` when `alphaViewModel.Beta` is null, but this relies on passing the field names as strings.

Is there another way to prevent validation of `BetaViewModel` fields when `alphaViewModel.Beta` is null?

Comment: You need to delete the `= new BetaViewModel()` so that it does not get initialized - once its initialized, then the validation kicks in. But in

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke - when I tried it before without initializing I got null pointer exceptions using the `EditorFor(...` ASP.NET helper which is why I initialized it. However, now removing the initialization works (I must have changed the view somehow) so your first comment is my accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to start by removing the `= new BetaViewModel();` from your `Beta` property. The `DefaultModelBinder` will initialize your `AlphaViewModel` in the POST method if the request contains any name/value pairs for the model.

That in turn initializes the `BetaViewModel` because of the `= new BetaViewModel()`. Because its not `null`, validation is triggered for the `Location` and `Area` properties and `ModelState` is invalid.

However there are other issues with your implementation. Take the case of a user checking the `HasBeta` property and starting to enter a value for `Location`, then realizes their mistake and unchecks the checkbox. Because the form control is hidden you will not get a client side validation error (hidden inputs are not validated by default), but a name/value pair is now sent for `Beta.Location`. That in turn will initialize the `BetaViewModel` and because a value has not been entered for `Area`, `ModelState` is invalid. Assuming you return the view in that case, the user has no idea what is going on because the error message is also hidden (they just keep hitting the submit button until they give up in frustration).

You could include a script to either disable the `BetaViewModel` inputs or ensure they have `null` values before submitting if the checkbox is unchecked.

Another option is to use conditional validation attributes, such as a [foolproof](https://github.com/leniel/foolproof) `[RequiredIf]`. Then use a single model containing all properties

```
public class AlphaViewModel
{
    [HiddenInput]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ....
    bool HasBeta { get; set; }

    // Include properties from BetaViewModel
    [HiddenInput]
    [RequiredIf("HasBeta ", true)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [RequiredIf("HasBeta ", true, ErrorMessage = "...")]
    public string Location { get; set; }
    [RequiredIf("HasBeta ", true, ErrorMessage = "...")]
    public string Area { get; set; }
}
```